# C ++ switch statements

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for school. I have never taken C++ before, so go easy on me.

My professor gave us some code, and wanted us to change the data type from a `char` to a `string`. That's not so bad, but then he wants us to change the `if else` statements to `case` statements. From what I understand about `case` statements, it needs to be like `case 1:`, and where the `1` is, I don't think I am allowed to put a letter instead.

Here is the code, and the problem for reference:

> Instructions:
>
> 1. Edit code so that the user can enter upper or lower case f or m using a string property.
> 2. Edit the code from if/else to case statements
>
> Code:
>
> ```cpp
> // Chapter 4 Exer 18
> // BMI
> #include <iostream>
> #include <iomanip>
> #include <string>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {
>   // Variables input by user
>   char gender;
>
>   double bodyWeight;
>   double wristMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>   double waistMeasurementAtNavel;
>   double hipMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>   double forearmMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>   double waistMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>
>   // Variables used for calculations
>   double A1, A2, A3, A4, A5;
>   double B;
>   double bodyFat;
>   double bodyFatPercentage;
>
>   cout << "Enter your gender (F or M): ";
>   cin >> gender;
>   cout << endl;
>    
>   // Female BMI
>   if (gender == 'F' || gender == 'f')
>   {
>       cout << "Enter body weight (in pounds): ";
>       cin >> bodyWeight;
>       cout << endl;
>    
>       cout << "Enter wrist measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
>       cin >> wristMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>       cout << endl;
>
>       cout << "Enter waist measurement at navel (in inches): ";
>       cin >> waistMeasurementAtNavel;
>       cout << endl;
>
>       cout << "Enter hip measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
>       cin >> hipMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>       cout << endl;
>
>       cout << "Enter forearm measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
>       cin >> forearmMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>       cout << endl;
>
>       // BMI Calculations
>       A1 = bodyWeight * 0.732 + 8.987;
>       A2 = wristMeasurementAtFullestPoint / 3.140;
>       A3 = waistMeasurementAtNavel * 0.157;
>       A4 = hipMeasurementAtFullestPoint * 0.249;
>       A5 = forearmMeasurementAtFullestPoint * 0.434;
>       B = A1 + A2 - A3 - A4 + A5;
>       bodyFat = bodyWeight - B;
>       bodyFatPercentage = bodyFat * 100 / bodyWeight;
>
>       cout << "Body fat: " << bodyFat << endl;
>       cout << "Body fat percentage: " << bodyFatPercentage << endl;
>   }
>   // Male BMI
>   else if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')
>   {
>       cout << "Enter body weight (in pounds): ";
>       cin >> bodyWeight;
>       cout << endl;
>    
>       cout << "Enter waist measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
>       cin >> waistMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
>       cout << endl;
>
>       // BMI Calculations
>       A1 = bodyWeight * 1.082 + 94.42;
>       A2 = waistMeasurementAtFullestPoint * 4.15;
>       B = A1 - A2;
>       bodyFat = bodyWeight - B;
>       bodyFatPercentage = bodyFat * 100 / bodyWeight;
>
>       cout << "Body fat: " << bodyFat << endl;
>       cout << "Body fat percentage: " << bodyFatPercentage << endl;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       cout << "Invalid gender code." << endl;
>   }
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Characters are integer types, so it is perfectly legal to `switch(gender) { case 'F': case 'f': ... `.

Comment: There's also `tolower()` which halves the number of tests you have to do.

Comment: @tadman It may not be true that the number of tests would be halfved. As far as I know it is not specified how switch must be compiled, but it usually it creates a jump table, so there are no comparisons at all. Its just like "jump to this pointer+char" with new jumps on that location that depend on what is in the case block. Also "tolower()" has comparisons in it, I think.

Comment: @tadman When writing my first comment, I thought youre talking about switch and not if (now I am not sure). When you want to speed optimize "if(a || b)" you can try "if(a | b)". Comparisons are fast, if the are not used to generate coditional jumps. So if it is really fast (like in this case) to test condition "b" you can test both "a" and "b" independent of the result of statement "a" and then bitwise "or"the result. This way you minimize the number of the conditional jumps when using "if", what is properly what your actual goal is.

Comment: @jjj `if (a | b)` is going to do *binary math* and has no hope of working here. What I mean is `switch (tolower(gender))`.

Comment: @tadman since == returns 0 or not (depending on wheter its equal or not) this works perfectly fine. The bitwise or could be faster, because the pipeline stays filled when you use less conditional jumps.

Comment: @jjj It sounds a lot like you're trying to out-smart the optimizer at the expense of making your code absolutely baffling and confusing to anyone used to normal C++. Don't do that. Please. For everyone's sake, especially your own. Do `(a || b)` if you mean to do a logical comparison. Only use `|` for explicitly bitwise operations.

Comment: @jjj Remember `||` is *short-circuit evaluated* as in it will only run until it finds a term that evaluates as truthful. `|` is *not*, it will run *to completion* since the compiler presumes you care about the exact result. This means `a() | b() | c()` where each of those is an expensive function call performs *significantly* slower than `a() || b() || c()` where `a()` usually has it covered. Your "optimization", like so many of these "life-hack" style tricks, does the exact opposite of its intent.

Comment: @jjj This holds for `&` vs. `&&` as well. The first failure in an `&&` chain causes it to bail out. Not so for `&` which just keeps going until it's done.

Comment: @tardman I wrote that it could be faster when it is very fast to check the singe conditions. When it is more than a simple comparison the bitwise approach is obviously slower.

Answer (score 1):

switch-case and UPPERCASE letters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Variables input by user
    char gender;

    double bodyWeight;
    double wristMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
    double waistMeasurementAtNavel;
    double hipMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
    double forearmMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
    double waistMeasurementAtFullestPoint;

    // Variables used for calculations
    double A1, A2, A3, A4, A5;
    double B;
    double bodyFat;
    double bodyFatPercentage;

    
    
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your gender (F or M): ";
        cin >> gender;
        if (gender >= 'a' && gender <= 'z')
        {
            gender = gender - 32; // cast to UPPERCASE
        }
        cout << gender << endl;
        
        // Female BMI
        switch (gender)
        {
        case 'F':
            cout << "Enter body weight (in pounds): ";
            cin >> bodyWeight;
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter wrist measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
            cin >> wristMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter waist measurement at navel (in inches): ";
            cin >> waistMeasurementAtNavel;
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter hip measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
            cin >> hipMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter forearm measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
            cin >> forearmMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
            cout << endl;

            // BMI Calculations
            A1 = bodyWeight * 0.732 + 8.987;
            A2 = wristMeasurementAtFullestPoint / 3.140;
            A3 = waistMeasurementAtNavel * 0.157;
            A4 = hipMeasurementAtFullestPoint * 0.249;
            A5 = forearmMeasurementAtFullestPoint * 0.434;
            B = A1 + A2 - A3 - A4 + A5;
            bodyFat = bodyWeight - B;
            bodyFatPercentage = bodyFat * 100 / bodyWeight;

            cout << "Body fat: " << bodyFat << endl;
            cout << "Body fat percentage: " << bodyFatPercentage << endl;
            break;

            // Male BMI
        case 'M':
            cout << "Enter body weight (in pounds): ";
            cin >> bodyWeight;
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter waist measurement at fullest point (in inches): ";
            cin >> waistMeasurementAtFullestPoint;
            cout << endl;

            // BMI Calculations
            A1 = bodyWeight * 1.082 + 94.42;
            A2 = waistMeasurementAtFullestPoint * 4.15;
            B = A1 - A2;
            bodyFat = bodyWeight - B;
            bodyFatPercentage = bodyFat * 100 / bodyWeight;

            cout << "Body fat: " << bodyFat << endl;
            cout << "Body fat percentage: " << bodyFatPercentage << endl;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid gender code." << endl;
        }
    } while (gender != 'M' && gender != 'F');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. When I tried running the code here it will ask me for the gender input but then it stops after that? any reason that would be?

Comment: try to add `getchar();` before the `return 0;` if you want to stay at the "running" screen

Comment: just gave that a try, same thing happens I select what gender I want then the code finishes before I can put in any of the BMI information.

Comment: Try debugging the code - put breakpoints at the right places and run it.

Comment: awesome i got it to run correctly now but my only other questions is does this satisfy the first requirement of the assignment? "  Edit code so that the user can enter upper or lower case f or m using a string property" i don't see anything about a string in there. sorry for the questions i am really new and my professor kinda sucks. ty

Comment: I added a condition before the whole switch-case that casts the input to UPPERCASE, the user still can enter lowercase or other letters (not `f / F` or `m / M`)